# Rails, cannot get Amazon AWS S3 to precompile locally before push to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I had a problem with heroku and my stylesheets not working on deployment and it says to try and precompile locally then commit this to git then push. I do `bundle exec rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` .
In trying to do this I get error;

Full Trace

```
C:\Sites\Peoples_Profiles>bundle exec rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rails aborted!
KeyError: key not found: "S3_ACCESS_KEY"
C:/Sites/Peoples_Profiles/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:6:in `fetch'
C:/Sites/Peoples_Profiles/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:118:in `configure'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
C:/Sites/Peoples_Profiles/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

[here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/developer-guide/setup-config.html#aws-ruby-sdk-credentials-environment) on amazon website it says how to set ENV vars locally so you can precompile everything locally which I have done and in my rails ENV they are listed

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
```

I am using carrierwave for my image handling and have everything set in my initializer correctly

carrier_wave.rb

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.aws_credentials = {
     # Configuration for Amazon S3

    access_key_id:     ENV.fetch('S3_ACCESS_KEY'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('S3_SECRET_KEY'),
    region:            ENV.fetch('S3_REGION') # Required
}
    config.storage    = :aws
    config.aws_bucket = ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET')  
  end
end
```

Im not sure what I am doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Can you confirm you have set the S3_ACCESS_KEY as environmet variable on Heroku ?

Comment: Hi. Yes everything is set at heroku correctly, I just found my problem when compiling locally Amazon says for example to `set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id` so instead of `S3_ACCESS_KEY` in carrier_wave.rb I need `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` instead, and same goes for the rest but setting the bucket I am still figuring out :D

Comment: Ok all good now. setting bucket is just `AWS_BUCKET` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would post a answer on this incase any one in future needs it. Use for windows in cmd line,

```
set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id_here
set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
set AWS_REGION=...
set AWS_BUCKET=...
```

Will set your `ENV` variables locally so you can compile. Set these in your carrier_wave.rb eg  `S3_ACCESS_KEY` becomes `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` etc. Compile everything for production. Then change everything back in your carrier_wave.rb back to `S3_ACCESS_KEY` etc. Then add everything with git and deploy.

**EDIT** Just simply use `set S3_ACCESS_KEY=djkhaskdhfaskdjhf` etc etc